# Recover error WshShell.exec

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, sqlplus

I use this command to execute a SQL query

```
Set cmd = WshShell.Exec("cmd /c set ORACLE_SID="& SERVICE &" && "& ORACLE_HOME & "\BIN\sqlplus.exe -s / as sysdba @C:\teste\nscp_supevision\scripts\teste\requete_vbs\requete_sql_etat_bdd.sql")
```

it works but I wonder how to handle the case where there is an error in the command

```
"cmd /c set ORACLE_SID="& SERVICE &" && "& ORACLE_HOME & "\BIN\sqlplus.exe -s / as sysdba @C:\teste\nscp_supevision\scripts\teste\requete_vbs\requete_sql_etat_bdd.sql"
```

I tried to get that error with a `cmd.exitcode` a `Err.Number` value referred is always 0 even if I put a mistake in my command.

PS: we should not I use a text file

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ExitCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/za76z6hh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property of the WshScriptExec object.